# Windows 10 "ipconfig /renew" not working

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, ip

My internet connection has lately been really unstable, I tried refreshing the connection by typing "ipconfig /renew" into my CMD (along with a few other commands... I used this http://www.wikihow.com/Refresh-Your-IP-Address-on-a-Windows-Computer). But it gave me an error saying

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\eames>ipconfig /renew

Windows IP Configuration

No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 3 while it has its media disconnected.

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::--------:1a5c:bfe6%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.----------
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.------

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:-----------:3938:2698:6b95
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::494:3938:2698:6b95%12
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local

C:\Users\eames>ipconfig /renew

Windows IP Configuration

No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 3 while it has its media disconnected.

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::------------:bfe6%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.---------
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.------

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:------------------:6b95
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::-----------:6b95%12
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local

C:\Users\eames>
```

Note, it says "No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 3 while it has its media disconnected." I'm no networking expert, but that does sound like a problem to me. Does anybody know what's going on? Here's what pops up when I use the "ipconfig /all" command:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : EamesLaptop
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : local

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-57------------
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-57-18-86-E7-BE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::--------:1a5c:bfe6%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.--------(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, February 9, 2016 6:21:22 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, February 10, 2016 6:32:09 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 140531480
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-60-75-84-60-57-18-86-E7-BE
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:-----:3c39:2f98:2698:6b95(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe8----------2698:6b95%12(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 520093696
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-60-75-84-60-57-18-86-E7-BE
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\eames>
```

I'm using a Linksys router... This has been giving me problems for quite a while now so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have always done a "release all" before the renew command.

Comment: Dumb question, but do you happen to have say a controller for your wireless card as well as the windows wireless trying to compete for controlling your wireless card? 

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Make me think you might have two things trying to control your wireless at once and they're conflicting.

Try also, ipconfig /release all as well.

Comment: @MattKing I know, it probably is dumb, but I really do know nothing about this topic. I am using an extender btw, on top of my router

Comment: Could this be a conflict of signals with the extender being too close to the router?  not my area so I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireless Local Area Connection 3 is a Microsoft Virtual Adapter as you can see in your second post.  It will not renew because it is not connected to anything.

Your wireless LAN adapter Wifi does have an IP address.  `ipconfig /renew` will not renew adapters that have no connection.  Every computer with wireless and an Ethernet port will have an error like this if they are not both connected.

It is usually better to do an `ipconfig /release` before doing an `ipconfig /renew` just to make sure it clears,  look at your adapters when you do the release first and you will see your IP is getting renewed.

That's all you asked about but you mention, `this has been giving me problems for quite a while`, have you been seeing this error a while or is there a real problem?

Comment: Well, this is very annoying for me when I'm playing online games. Just browsing the internet or watching videos usually isn't a problem, but when i play a game like 'Counter Strike' on 'Steam', it will keep disconnecting me temporarily from the servers every few minutes. Sometimes, I can fix it by disconnecting and reconnecting but that doesn't always work... so you can see, it's a very frustrating problem. Also, I'm using an extender/repeater on top of my router.

Comment: @Eames This answers the question you posed. If you want to solve your connectivity problems, make a question about that problem. If/when you do that, please include the research and trials you've done already.

Comment: `ipconfig /release` will not work when you have the message "No operation can be performed on Ethernet while it has its media disconnected."

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is open the device manager mmc devmgmt.msc - highlight the problem hardware and hit the delete key - do not put a check in the delete software option - At the top click the Action section and click on Scan for hardware changes.  Your network adapter will be reinstalled and the ipconfig utility will work again

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error along with a BSOD for `DRIVER POWER STATE FAILURE` - tried numerous options but resorted to replacing the hardware - suspect it was related to recent power spike / outage due to electrical upgrades.

Also resorted to testing various dongles - nothing seemed to work, may try re-imaging but this is a [hard system fault to recover from](https://superuser.com/questions/1139757/driver-power-state-failure-bsod-installing-windows-10).