# Driver Power State Failure BSOD Installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bsod, windows-installation

I'm trying to do a fresh install of windows 10 on an Acer Aspire R3 Laptop from a usb key. I can get right through the installation until it asks you for a wifi connection, and then for privacy settings etc. After that it runs for a while, goes to a black screen for 5 minutes and then shows a bsod with stop code *Driver Power State Failure*

I can't seem to find a solution because everything I find assumes you can at least boot to safe mode. I can boot from the usb and get to a command prompt, but I haven't been able to find any more information from there. I have tried wiping and reinstalling several times.

The original reason for reinstalling from scratch was because explorer was crashing within a few minutes of booting and wasn't recoverable. When trying to restore or *Reset My PC* from safe mode it also failed with a less than useful *Something went wrong..* message so I decided to go all out,  wipe the drive and reinstall with a usb image downloaded from my other laptop.

So, how can I find more information about what's causing the crash?

Update:

I tried again with the 1607 build of windows 10 but this did not solve the issue. I was busy working out how to insert drivers into the Boot.wim when the laptop owner found out they had been paying for extended support (!) so I sent it back to PC world and they sorted it out.

Comment: I've had similar issues, and found I needed to download the latest Windows 10 build, rather than the original release that was on my Acer.

Comment: which version do you try to install? 1511 or 1607?

Comment: The version in the cmd bar says 10.0.14393, I just used the Media Creation Tool to create the installer on the usb drive a few days ago so I assumed it would be the latest version. Windows 10 Home x64.

Comment: oo, this is 1607. Get a proper ISO and try again: http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557 if this still fails, insert the latest drivers into the Boot.wim and install.wim with DISM