# Wi-Fi doesn't have a valid IP configuration error

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I am using HP ab522tx laptop. Windows 10 auto downloaded some updates like 10-15 days back. It always used to give me a reminder to install the same but I used to just put the laptop on sleep mode after using it. Today suddenly it hung on me for the first time.

I long pressed the power key to turn it off and then switched it on. The option to install the updates was there when it turned on. I selected install and restart and then it restarted without even showing that they same were installed. Anyways the updates to be installed notification was gone from the start button after it restarted. Now the version of the Windows which is installed is Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1023)

[image]

I don't know which was the build which was previously installed so I can't say whether this update was correctly installed or not.

Now everything works fine but to every Wi-Fi that I connect to, shows the no internet error:

[image]

Did some basic troubleshooting and it lead me to this error:  Wi-Fi doesn't have a valid IP configuration

[image: https://imgur.com/a/JELlelh]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/VjY1ibW]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/NtbXMvi]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/dsRwtcA]

Googled, found many articles and websites. Followed steps mentioned on this one https://windowsreport.com/wi-fi-valid-ip-configuration-windows-10/

1. Uninstalled driver, restarted and it was auto installed again. Same issue

[image: https://imgur.com/a/85pH1YC]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/etpkscL]

2. Reset TCP/IP. Done. Same issue. It shows this

[image: https://imgur.com/a/adqyjlu]

3. Change the wireless SSID and password

Not done but tried connecting the laptop to other Wi-Fi connections. Same result.

4. Set the channel width to Auto

Done. Same result.

5. Set your IP address manually

Didn't do. As I don't know what values to fill in.

6. Remove your antivirus software

Using Windows Defender only. It is not messing up with the Wi-Fi. Disabled just to check but same result.

7-10. Didn't follow those points as I somehow feel that the issue is not with those.

`
**Edit-**

Please check all photos, I think the problem is somewhere in them. I am just not able to find it.

Connected a wifi adapter to the laptop https://www.amazon.in/TP-Link-TL-WN725N-150Mbps-Wireless-Adapter/dp/B008IFXQFU/ref=mp_s_a_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=tp+link+wifi+adapter&qid=1626514066&sr=8-2 but same result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyWf6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY9YW.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EluuI.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9x3u.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vn3j.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDhje.jpg

Adapter list minus the wifi adapter which was connected, the connected adapter was auto renamed to wi-fi 2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s4Uq.jpg

Started again from scratch. Reference video, same as the link followed earlier https://windowsreport.com/wi-fi-valid-ip-configuration-windows-10/

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VgwCcKpv38E

Step 1

netsh winsock reset     works fine

netsh int ip reset           gives that error as shown in the first post but it gives that error in this video also though mine is more with a little more settings or something.

I restarted but it didn't work. So, tried the next commands

ipconfig /release

ipconfig /flushds

ipconfig /renew

And I get this error No operation can be performed on ethernet etc. while it has its media disconnected (What is this and how to resolve this?)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v96H.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KCfH.jpg

Zoomed in

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKGeQ.jpg

Found this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-get-an-error-media-disconnected-when-i-try-to/e0541113-cc92-40e6-84fa-1ebb8ac0fd24 but I wasn't able to fix it with the steps mentioned in the suggested answer. These are the suggested commands

netsh winsock reset

netsh winsock reset catalog

netsh int ip stop

netsh int ip start

The last two commands are not found by the system

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IpAY.jpg

[Windows 10 "ipconfig /renew" not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1037686/windows-10-ipconfig-renew-not-working) this link says to use ipconfig /release before doing an ipconfig /renew. Did that and same results

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dgez.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXFK3.jpg

Please help

Comment: So did you restart/reset your router as it suggested?

Comment: what do you get with `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: @harrymc Sorry as a new user I am not allowed to post all the links so I put in some spaces between them.

Comment: @DavidPostill I connect either to a portable hotspot device or to my phone's hotstpot. Did restart/reset them but same result. All other devices connect fine to these devices.

Comment: Did you try to install the [REALTEK RTL8723BE driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8723be-software)?

Comment: @Albin Please check the edited original post.

Comment: @harrymc Please check the edited original post. Which version from your link should I give a try? Both were released on the same date, only the version number is different.

Comment: @billubakra please specificity which picture has the result of `ipconfig /all`, I not gonna look through all the images

Comment: you are randomly trying solutions for a cause you don't know yet, you don't have to post everything that does not work. less will be more in this case! And please make screenshots not photos, this is really unbearable.

Comment: The big download is for WLAN and Bluetooth. The small one is for WLAN only.

Comment: @billubakra 95% of info in question has nothing to do with issue _(only screenshot relevant: Device Manager)_. Please post output of `ipconfig /all` within a code box _(don't screenshot terminals - copy/paste output into a code box)_. The issue is one of four things in order of relevance: **(1)**  Router's DHCP/DNS server _(reboot router → login to its WebUI → Network page)_; **(2)** Random Windows driver/network issue _(reboot PC)_; **(3)** Firewall blocking DHCP and/or DNS **(4)** Manual config of network adapter _(`ncpa.cpl` → Right-click adapter → Properties → IPv4 → Properties → General)_

Comment: @Albin Sorry will post ss's from now on. ipconfig /all https://pastebin.com/Fj27yKW4 Same thing from a pc on the same wifi https://pastebin.com/sDC4gsAQ

Comment: @harrymc will try the shorter file and will get back

Comment: @JW0914 ipconfig /all https://pastebin.com/Fj27yKW4 Same thing from a pc on the same wifi https://pastebin.com/sDC4gsAQ 1. Using my phone as a hotspot so no router. 2. Disabled and uninstalled the realtek driver restarted and it was reinstalled again. 3. How to fix it? 4. https://imgur.com/a/idBKwRV what values to fill here?

Comment: Filled the numbers manually, left the dns server empty as didn't know what to fill there. From unidentified network it has started showing the wifi's name
https://imgur.com/a/OJZwY0Y
https://imgur.com/a/0SW7UNA
https://imgur.com/a/5LURrnO

Comment: Edit- Connected to a new hotspot, another phone basically, using the same values in ipv4 etc. as filled above and it shows unidentified network
https://imgur.com/a/sYpw9HU Changed it to auto select the ipv4, subnet etc. and it says identifying

https://imgur.com/a/je34Ouw

Comment: @billubakra The [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Fj27yKW4) [linked to](https://superuser.com/questions/1663002/wi-fi-doesnt-have-a-valid-ip-configuration-error#comment2549095_1663002) shows a valid IP configuration for the WiFi adapter, so the issue is with the hotspot. Many carriers block hotspot internet access from a phone unless a fee is paid _(can be circumvented with a rooted device)_, however if that's a feature you have, reach out to the carrier, as it's either that or the DNS of the hotspot _(try setting the hotspot's DNS to [`1.1.1.1`](https://1.1.1.1/))_.

Comment: @JW0914 It has nothing to do with the carrier. Here one can use phone's internet as hotspot with any device. Please read the original post, this issue started after I kept on ignoring the downloaded update for weeks. The phone's hotspot works fine in other systems. DNS set to 1.1.1.1, alternate 8.8.8.8 now it shows wifí's name under the wifi adapter https://imgur.com/a/5LURrnO but still says no internet. If I troubleshoot now it showed that networking reset will fix it, did the reset the system restarted but the same issue is there. Wifi doesn't have a valid ip configuration error is gone now.

Comment: @JW0914 After restart wifi doesn't have a valid ip configuration error is back.

Comment: @billubakra Unless your PC's firewall is blocking the ports for DHCP and DNS, this is an issue with the hotspot, as that's where WiFi clients get the subnet, gateway, and DNS addresses from - this has nothing to do with Windows or the PC _(unless you're unable to connect to other WiFi networks with the PC)_ and sounds like a DHCP server issue on the hotspot. If you manually assign the PC a subnet IP within the hotspot's subnet, with the gateway and DNS set to the hotspot's IP, and you have WAN access, it's a DHCP server issue. If not, it's an issue with the hotspot's DNS server.

Comment: @JW0914 I think I got you confused there. This pc in question is not connecting to any wifi at all. It shows the same error with every wifi. But if I connect the same wifi, forget about them being from a hotspot from a mobile as I have checked and in my country it is legal to use it, to other systems it works fine. PC's firewall has nothing to do with it too as I have checked them too. If I have to manually fill the values of ip4, gateway, dns then can you look at the two pastebin links above and guide as in what values to fill in? Please note that both systems were on the same wifi.

Comment: @harrymc Installed the version 2023.56.0502.2017 from the realtek website but after restarting this version was showing up
https://imgur.com/a/bqkJLM0
If I uninstall it and then let the system install it, the same version shows up. This version is present on the hp's website
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-15-ab500-notebook-pc-series/9068229/model/9329819
The one installed in the system is 2024.0.4.208 dated 26.05.19 and as per their website it is 2024.0.4.108 dated 05.06.19 What should I do?

Comment: Your driver is from Realtek and more recent than the one I found, so is the preferred version. So forget about my driver. As nothing helps, it might be worthwhile to check for a hardware problem. Try to connect an external wifi adapter via USB, to see if it does better.

Comment: @harrymc Connected a wifi adapter https://www.amazon.in/TP-Link-TL-WN725N-150Mbps-Wireless-Adapter/dp/B008IFXQFU/ref=mp_s_a_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=tp+link+wifi+adapter&qid=1626514066&sr=8-2 but kept on receiving the same error. This issue popped up after the system froze and due to my mistake of delaying to apply the downloaded update.

Comment: @harrymc Check what I have mentioned on the ss's Some more details

Manually filled

https://imgur.com/a/tEDFYOi

https://imgur.com/a/1xzEEoh

Automatic

https://imgur.com/a/wL8As4g

https://imgur.com/a/T9R47T4

https://imgur.com/a/9XjlXC3           This error is still there :(

https://imgur.com/a/avu9pd7

https://imgur.com/a/y0LgMwc

Comment: Again following this link https://windowsreport.com/wi-fi-valid-ip-configuration-windows-10/ and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgwCcKpv38E\
Followed first point again, result
https://zerobin.net/?7c835d7bc312303b#6VUpKNG7Jt2aSrywYFiIjJfHLHRNOSXXkl7HXnclGqU=
No gateway shown in ipconfig /release
umable to contact your dhcp server error in wifi.
The same wifi, connected via hotspot from a phone, is working fine in 10+ devices

Comment: Too many strange problems. Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: The last update was downloaded like in first week of July. It always used to show me a notification to install it. But I kept on ignoring it and put the laptop in sleep mode. Now after the system froze and I restarted it, that update was gone. It didn't install as there was no sign of the installation windows. Now the update history shows me the last update which was installed in June. I cannot revert it back because it has been more than 10 days. The update page shows me a new update but I cannot download and install it as I cannot connect to the internet. contd..

Comment: Where are the downloaded update files stored? Can I install the last update which was downloaded and I delayed it, manually? https://imgur.com/a/21f6XLI

https://imgur.com/a/1aFqJxn

https://imgur.com/a/7SjIZWW         @harrymc

Comment: Try first my above advice.

Comment: @harrymc https://imgur.com/a/X8CjQQM check the MS and superuser forum commands https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-get-an-error-media-disconnected-when-i-try-to/e0541113-cc92-40e6-84fa-1ebb8ac0fd24 https://superuser.com/questions/1037686/windows-10-ipconfig-renew-not-working. I followed this link to fix the Netsh int ip error https://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/netsh-int-ip-reset-says-access-denied/

Comment: @billubakra _(Microsoft Answers forum is almost always a waste of time)_ Your question really needs cleaning up, as there shouldn't be this many comments due to a lack of clarity in the question. Perform a repair install of Windows, as it's more efficient than trying to troubleshoot at this point: Download the [Media Creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) → Choose to install on another PC to save the `windows.iso` → Extract ISO to folder on a partition other than `C:` → Launch `setup.exe` _**while booted to Windows**_ → Choose to keep all files and settings

Comment: Your problem seems to defy every fix. Try doing [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is the same as doing a major upgrade of Windows.